# Scala string to case class

Tags: scala, case-class, type-level-computation

I want to parse the generic string to case class object.

```
case class Book(isbn: String)

val b = Book("123")

b.toString // "Book(123)"



trait CaseClassParser[A] {
 val prefix = A.getClass.getName // Not work
 def read(str: String): A = {
  Parser.parse....
 }
}
```

I want to know is there any way to get the holes' name the type parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "generic string to case class"? Where do those case-classes come from? Do they guarantee anything about what their `toString`-method looks like?

Comment: Result of `toString` (often) bears too little information for you to reliably recover case class instance from it. Formats designed to store the data more reliably e.g. JSON are better starting point. Which is why said JSON is used as a default for Decoders/Encoders in Circe and a lot of other libraries.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I just want to recover one possible case class from the string which is from toString of the case class. For example, from "Book(123)" I want to generate case class Book(a:String) or Book(a:Int).

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Actually, I am not care about the correct schema. I just want to recover one possible case class from string. For example, from "Book(123)" I want to generate case class Book(a:String) or Book(a:Int). I think I need some type level programming and Macro, but I don't know how to do it in scala.